# type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' in type cast what couse this type of error

Tags: flutter, dart

i am having this problem and trying to look for solution i have to pages LOCATION page with has static function which fetch locations by id and MAIN page which has router function to route between locations.. here is code bellow.

LOCATION PAGE where static method was declared

```
 import 'package:tourism_app/models/location_fact.dart';
   class Location{
   final int id;
  String name;
  String imageParth;
  final List<LocationFact> facts;

  Location(this.id, this.name, this.imageParth, this.facts);


  static List<Location> fetchAll() {
    return [
      Location(1,'1Arashiyama Bamboo Grove', 'assets/images/kiyomizu-dera.jpg', [
        LocationFact('Summary',
            'While we could go on about the ethereal glow and seemingly endless heights of this bamboo grove on the 
   outskirts of Kyoto, the sight\'s pleasures extend beyond the visual realm.'),
        LocationFact('How to Get There',
            'Kyoto airport, with several terminals, is located 16 kilometres south of the city and is also known as 
    Kyoto. Kyoto can also be reached by transport links from other regional airports.'),
      ]),
      Location(2,'1Arashiyama Bamboo Grove 2', 'assets/images/kiyomizu-dera.jpg', [
        LocationFact('Summary',
            'While we could go on about the ethereal glow and seemingly endless heights of this bamboo grove on the 
    outskirts of Kyoto, the sight\'s pleasures extend beyond the visual realm.'),
        LocationFact('How to Get There',
            'Kyoto airport, with several terminals, is located 16 kilometres south of the city and is also known as 
    Kyoto. Kyoto can also be reached by transport links from other regional airports.'),
      ]),
      Location(3,'1Arashiyama Bamboo Grove 3', 'assets/images/kiyomizu-dera.jpg', [
        LocationFact('Summary',
            'While we could go on about the ethereal glow and seemingly endless heights of this bamboo grove on the 
  outskirts of Kyoto, the sight\'s pleasures extend beyond the visual realm.'),
          LocationFact('How to Get There',
            'Kyoto airport, with several terminals, is located 16 kilometres south of the city and is also known as Kyoto. Kyoto can also be reached by transport links from other regional airports.'),
      ]),
    ];
  }

  static Location? fetchByid(int locationID)
  {
    //fetch all the location iterate then when we find locations
    //with ID we want return them immediatly
    List<Location> locations = Location.fetchAll();
    for(var i=0; i<locations.length; i++)
    {
      if(locations[i].id == locationID)
      {
        return locations[i];
      }

    }
    return null;


  }
}
```

Mian page: where route function is declared to navigate between locations

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'screens/locations/locations.dart';
import 'screens/location_detail.dart';

const LocationsRoute = "/";
const LocationDetailRout = '/location_detail';

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      onGenerateRoute: _routes(),
    );
  }

  RouteFactory _routes() {
    return (settings) {
     // final Map<String, dynamic> arguments = settings.arguments;
      final arguments = settings.arguments as Map<String, dynamic>;
      Widget screen;
      switch (settings.name) {
        case LocationsRoute:
          screen = Locations();
          break;
        case LocationDetailRout:
          screen = LocationDetail(arguments['id']);
      }
    };
  }


}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68896263/type-null-is-not-a-subtype-of-type-mapstring-object-in-type-cast could anyone please help me with this problem

Answer (score 0):

### Update

#### Simple Named Routes

Any simple named routes should be passed to the `routes` argument:

```dart
MaterialApp(
  ...,
  routes: {
    LocationsRoute: (_) => Locations(), //<-- Simple routes
  }
);
```

#### Complex Routes With Arguments

For any routes that need arguments, you should make an `onGenerateRoute` method instead of a RouteFactory:

```dart
Route<dynamic>? _onGenerateRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
  if(settings.name == LocationDetailRout) {
    final arguments = settings.arguments as Map<String, dynamic>;
    return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => LocationDetail(arguments['id']));
  }
  return null;
}
```

Pass this method to the `MaterialApp`:

```dart
MaterialApp(
  onGenerateRoute: _onGenerateRoute,
  ...,
);
```

Comment: It throws this error?  Null check operator used on a null value

Comment: can you do `print(settings.arguments)` before my code and post the output?

Comment: it shows this Out Put.. RouteSettings("/", null).arguments

Comment: bro i did it but it showing me this error:=> The argument type 'dynamic Function(dynamic)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Route<dynamic>? Function(RouteSettings)?'

Comment: then just specify the type on return and input arguments @AhmedJaad. I've updated my function.

Comment: it did not work throwing this error: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' in type cast

Comment: did i send you send you the whole code so you go through then check them all..

Comment: this is the link of project on github: https://github.com/Ahmed-jad/tourism_app  thanks for your help