# type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, Object>' in type cast

Tags: flutter, dart

I am tryna add a TabBar and it gives me this error
by the way, I am new in the field and I dunno what to do ??
and I think the Error in Screen1 file

{type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, Object>' in type cast}

//main.dart
-->this is the Main file

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'screen1.dart';
import 'screen2.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      //home: MyHomePage(),
      initialRoute: '/',
      routes: {
        '/':(context) => MyHomePage(),
        '/x1':(context) => Screen1(),
        '/x2':(context) => Screen2(),
      },
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {

  void selectScreen(BuildContext ctx , int n){
    Navigator.of(ctx).pushNamed(
      n==1? '/x1':'/x2',
      arguments: {
        'id' : 10 ,
        'title' : "info1",
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 2 ,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Main Screen"),
          bottom: TabBar(
            tabs: <Widget>[
              Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.category), text: ("Screen1"),),
              Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.category), text: ("Screen2"),),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        body: TabBarView(
          children: <Widget>[
            Screen1(),
            Screen2(),
          ],
        ),
        drawerScrimColor: Colors.blue.withOpacity(0.3),
        drawer: Drawer(
          child: ListView(
            children: [
              ListTile(
                title: Text("Go to Screen 1", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30)),
                subtitle: Text("Go to Screen 1",),
                trailing: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios),
                onTap: (){selectScreen(context , 1);},
              ),
              ListTile(
                title: Text("Go to Screen 2", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30)),
                subtitle: Text("Go to Screen 2",),
                trailing: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios),
                onTap: (){selectScreen(context , 2);},
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

//screen1.dart
-->this is the Screen1 file

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Screen1 extends StatelessWidget {



  void selectScreen(BuildContext ctx){
    Navigator.of(ctx).pushReplacementNamed(
      '/x2',
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    final routeArg = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as Map<String , Object>;


    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Screen 1"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Text("Welcome To Screen 1" , style: TextStyle(fontSize: 35)),
            Text("${routeArg['id']}" , style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30)),
            Text("${routeArg['title']}" , style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30)),
            InkWell(
              child: Text("Go to Screen 2", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 35)),
              onTap: (){selectScreen(context);},
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

//screen2.dart
-->this is the Screen2 file

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'screen1.dart';

class Screen2 extends StatelessWidget {


  void selectScreen(BuildContext ctx){
    Navigator.of(ctx).pushReplacementNamed(
      '/x1',
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Screen 2"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Text("Welcome To Screen 2" , style: TextStyle(fontSize: 35)),
            Text("" , style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30)),
            InkWell(
              child: Text("Go to Screen 1", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 35)),
              onTap: (){selectScreen(context);},
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Console Output

```
Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone x86 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
Installing build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk...
Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:49802/QsEhHGWOV_M=/ws
Syncing files to device sdk gphone x86...

======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following _CastError was thrown building Screen1(dirty, dependencies: [_ModalScopeStatus]):
type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, Object>' in type cast

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  Screen1 file:///C:/Users/masa/Downloads/flutter-p/flutter_training/lib/main.dart:51:13
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      Screen1.build (package:flutter_training/screen1.dart:17:65)
#1      StatelessElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4648:28)
#2      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4574:15)
#3      Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4267:5)
#4      ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4553:5)
...
====================================================================================================
```

Comment: Welcome to Flutter and Stackoverflow, kindly provide the entire log which is printed in your console. That way it will be easier to find out what went wrong and where

Answer (score 0):

Try replace

```
final routeArg = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as Map<String , Object>
```

with:

```
if (ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings != null && ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings!.arguments != null)   { 
final routeArg = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as Map<String , Object>
} else {
final routeArg = { 'id' : 0, 'title' : ''};
}
```